# Postgres division incorrect and rows disappear in WITH query

Tags: postgresql

I have a `WITH AS` query, I hope the brevity can be appreciated, i've distilled this down to what the problem is:

```
WITH XX AS (
   SELECT ....,
   floor(GREATEST(value*-1, value2) * (value4*value5/value) * -1 * 100)/100 as x,
   ....
)
```

Then I use this later in the query

```
SELECT 1/x as "ratio" from XX
```

This is where a whole bunch of rows disappear,

now if i do:

```
SELECT 2/1*x "ratio" from XX
```

also weird is this returns the same result:

```
SELECT 2*1*x "ratio" from XX
```

The rows come back but the value of `ratio` is incorrect. I've tried to also use `CAST` but it will still return the incorrect result. Curiously the result is actually the result of 2*x instead of 2/x

Why is the result incorrect, and why do the rows disappear?

Comment: I don't see how any records could be disappearing without the presence of a `WHERE` clause.  Can you share any sample data with us?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its quite hard, the data sample is really long. I think the results disappear because of a division by 0, its really odd that changing the / operator to * returns the same result, maybe under the hood its a division by 0?

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing, that somehow your two queries differ in the presence/absence of a divide by zero.  The strange thing is that I usually get an error in Postgres if a query hits a divide by zero, but you are still getting back some data for some reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if i explicitly replace the x with 0 I get a division by 0 error too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 2/1*x "ratio" from XX
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT 2*1*x "ratio" from XX
```

because of multiplications and divisions are evaluated from left to right. Thus, the first expression is evaluated as `(2 / 1) * x`, and not as `2 / (1 * x)`.

BTW: Your arithmetics smell like integer arithmethics which should be done as float arithmetics, e.g. you better wrote the expression as `2.0 / x`.

Comment: Its weird but adding `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001` (or some really insignificant number to x seemed to solve the problem). Thank you for also helping with the RTL issue, I didn't know that (it was to add onto my issue)